# Is it possible to shorten this if statement?

Tags: c++

I simply want to know if I can make whats in the parenthesis of this if statement simpler.

```
if (augend[i]=='0' && partialSum[i]=='0' && carry=='0')
```

Such as `(augend[i] & partialsum[i] & carry == '0')`. I'm still learning so i'm not quite sure if something like this is possible.

Comment: It can be shorter. It probably should not be shorter.

Comment: @Tas Dead wrong. That would result in comparing `augend[i]` to the boolean result of the next `==`, and so forth.

Comment: Don't sweat on making it simpler, the compiler will make it efficient enough, just make certain it is readable and maintainable.

Comment: @Tas So delete it. Don't leave errors lying around to confuse people.

Comment: The alternative you suggest is not correct. You can make it textually shorter by storing carry as 0 or 1 rather than '0' or '1', but I'm curious as to the rest of the computation. You shouldn't need all this. Post the whole thing.

Comment: `(augend[i] ^ partialSum[i] ^ carry) == '0'` maybe. But why?

Comment: You could rearrange the expression to take advantage of short circuiting.

Comment: I'm not sure why you'd bother shortening this particular code; your focus should be on writing the clearest, most maintainable code. This seems to be the most obvious clear and maintainable solution. Technically, that `if` statement could be expressed as `if (x)`, but that'd reduce clarity and maintenance elsewhere, which is undesirable. Anything more local would likely be to niche to pass the "clear and maintainable" test.

Comment: You can make this shorter with a helper function, change my answer below.

Answer (score 4):

1. No, the numerical value for '0' is not `0`, but usually `48` (but that is not portable), so your bitwise trick will not work.
2. Even if bitwise tricks would be possible, **don't** do that. Leave the code as is, for it is clear and easy to understand.

What you're attempting to do is *premature micro-optimization* and ultimately a bad idea.

Comment: i think hes going for less typing, not optimization. Although that is optimization of a kind

Comment: @pm100 What the OP actually said was 'simpler'. Don't guess. It's up to the OP to clarify if necessary.

Comment: title says shorten, so you are guessing too

Comment: @pm100 And text says 'simpler'. OP needs to clarify.

Comment: @EJP it's OK to guess. It's nearly always necessary to make some assumptions in order to answer any question on this site. That doesn't mean that OP doesn't need to clarify however. (sorry, reposted this comment due to typo)

Answer (score 1):

Encapsulation:

```
bool zeros() {
    return true;
}
template<class... chars>
bool zeros(char x, chars... lst) {
    return x == '0' && zeros(lst...);
}
if (zeros(augend[i], partialSum[i], carry)){
     //impl//
}   

 //lined up just for size comparison
if (augend[i]=='0' && partialSum[i]=='0' && carry=='0')
if (zeros(augend[i], partialSum[i], carry))
```

This is more brief and becomes much much shorter the more parameters you have to compare (as you don't need to write `=='0'` each time).

---

If you need it for any char....

```
bool equal(char match) {
   return true;
}
template<class... chars>
bool equal(char match, char front, chars... lst) {
    return match == front && equal(match, lst...);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Nope, that's as short it can be

Comment: I'm sure if you *really* tried, it could be shorter. If you defined a function called `z` that checks if something `== '0'`, you could cut it down. It's a question of if you *should* though.

Comment: In *this* case creating a function comparing it to a constant value isn't necessary. And to have a shorter code you must name the function 1-2 letters, which can't really describe what the function is meant to be. Cleanest code would involve creating a function where the inputs are the 3 vars. *chk0(augend[i],partialSum[i],carry)*

Answer (score 0):

if these were ints rather than characters (ie carry == 0 is what you want) then you could do

```
if (!augend[i] && !partialSum[i] && !carry)
```

Since we dont know what you are doing its hard to say. But `if (carry)` and `if(!carry)` feel quite natural if you are doing some kind or arithmetic.

Comment: or `(!(augend[i] || partialSum[i] || carry))`

Answer (score 0):

you can do this:

```
if(augend[i]=='0' & partialSum[i]=='0' & carry=='0'){}
```

as == has greater precedence and will return bool on which bitwise operator can be used.

Comment: However, this isn’t, in general, a valid transformation, because it removes the short-circuiting that `&&` does.

Comment: @PeteBecker what do you mean by short-circuiting.

Comment: @AbhishekKumar -- for example: `if (ptr && *ptr == whatever)` checks whether `ptr` is a null pointer, and if it is, it skips the second part, which would be a disaster with a null pointer.

Answer (score 0):

You could do

```
if(!(augend[i]^'0'|partialSum[i]^'0'|carry^'0'))
```

This is an excellent way to make readers of your code, including probably future you, wonder what the *$#@ is going on.

In case the sarcasm wasn't clear, please DON'T actually do this.  (Unless this is for a "code golf" competition, in which case there would be a number of other things you could probably improve.)  Your original code is much better.

Comment: This doesn't perform short-circuit evaluation.  The logical operators perform short circuit evaluation.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews True, this is only equivalent if the original `[]` and `==` and `&&` had the built-in meanings.  (If there are no side effects or function calls, short circuit evaluation is not an observable behavior, just an optimization detail.)

Answer (score -1):

```
if (augend[i]==partialSum[i]==carry=='0')
```

or

```
(augend[i]==partialSum[i]==carry=='0') ? (if_true) : (if_false)
```